# How to use mobile deep linking by sending an email?

Tags: deep-linking

I would like to know how to send an email with a button saying "Change Password", where when it is clicked from a mobile device, it: (1) checks to see an app is on the device, (2) if not, ask if the person wants to install it and go on from there, (3) if the app is on the device, open the app and pass on some information to the app (in this case, the usual one-time reference code for changing password).

Is it possible to write a JavaScript code for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

That's possible, but your question is a bit broader then just having deep linking Email - you are asking about the creation of a deep link mechanism from scratch, that will also work when clicking from an email.

#### some background

In order to deep link to an app from mobile, you need to have:

1. some server that can catch the click domain and then try to deep link o redirect the user the store.
2. logics to handle different devices, platforms and browsers
3. logics to be able to deep link to the app or redirect to store otherwise
4. if it your app, you'll need to release a version that supports deep link, and set the deep link methodology that will fit the user's platform and browser.

I suggest first to read some material on:
 - URI Schemes
 - Universal Links in iOS
 - App Links in Android

#### steps to follow

I suggest first that you'll try to deep link to the app from a mobile browser when the app is installed. If your app does not support deep link, add that support. e.g. with URI schemes, try to do:

```js
window.location.href = "myappscheme://"
```

where myappscheme:// is your set URI scheme

Then you can try playing with the situation where the app is not installed, for example:

```js
window.location.href = "myappscheme://";
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = ...store_link...;
}, 1000);
```

The reason for `setTimeout` here is that if deep linking fails, you want to still be able to redirect the user to the store.

Later you can investigate support of Universal Links, to support iOS 9+ users.

#### Industry solutions

As you need to create everything from scratch, there are some solutions for this in the market, for example -

- https://www.appsflyer.com/resources/everything-marketer-needs-to-know-deep-linking/deep-linking-basics/
- https://www.appsflyer.com/resources/technical-guide-to-attribution-and-deep-linking

Comment: Do you have any pre-written code for sending such email (described above)?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by pre-written code? It depends on the mail provider you are using, but basically you'll need a button element with some onclick callback that will call you JavaScript code.

Comment: In fact I need an example working piece of code ( you mentioned it as JavaScript code) which should be called by onclick callback to 1) checks to see the app is on the device, (2) if not, ask if the person wants to install it and go on from there, (3) if the app is on the device, open the app and pass on some information to the app (in this case, the usual one-time reference code for changing password)

Comment: You can use the code on top. For your questions:
1. you can't check if the app is installed, as both iOS and Android not allow you to do so. This is why you have the timeout in the example above.
2. You can try raising a popup via JS, but it will not work on some browsers. Better methodology is to go to the store.
3. Passing information can be done via the URI scheme you are passing